# Why tomcat(64bit) can not access more than 4.5g of ram on windows server?

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-server-2012

We have an java web application deployed on tomcat8 and on windows server 2012.server has 16g of ram and we set options for tomcat to use maximum 8g of ram. But tomcat can not access more than 4.5g of ram and cpu usage goes  up to 100% and we have to restart tomcat. Why tomcat cant access more than 4.5g of ram? 
We also set jvm options to java on control panel as answerd on previous questions.

Comment: Can you enable GC logs for tomcat application and post them for period when you think tomcat use all available memory?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I'll post it as soon as posible.